# jQuery Ajax returns undefined result from asp.net core controller's POST action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Can't make friends out of my AJAX and MVC 6 controller.

This is how I define AJAX call for *SetFormValues* POST-action:

**Index.cshtml**

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "Home/SetFormValues",
    data: { Name: name, Phone: phone },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        SuccessFunction(result)
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("ALARM!");
    },
    async: false
})
```

I see that the controller works and executes *SetFormValues* action which is defined as the following:

**HomeController.cs**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SetFormValues(string Name, string Phone)
{
    string NameErrorStr = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name) ? "Обязательное поле" : string.Empty;
    string PhoneErrorStr = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Phone) ? "Обязательное поле" : string.Empty;

    var result = new { NameError = NameErrorStr, PhoneError = PhoneErrorStr };
    var jresult = Json(result);

    return jresult;
}
```

Debugger shows that action executes and my resulting JSON object fills correctly:
[image: Debugger enters SetFormValues action correctly]

Finally, his is how *SuccessFunction(result)* is defined:

**Index.cshtml again**

```js
function SuccessFunction(result) {
    alert("Success function shit executed. result=" +
        result + "NameError=" +
        result.NameError + ". PhoneError=" +
        result.PhoneError);

    $("#nameerror").append(result.NameError);
    $("#phoneerror").append(result.PhoneError);
}
```

Function works, alert is raised but result stay 'undefined' no matter what I do:
[image]

```
result = [object Object]
result.val = undefined
```

Maybe I have to deserialize JSON result properly or fill some properties in it's declaration above, I don't know.
I'm using the lattest libraries for jquery, validate and unobtrusive.
I also tried *JSON.parse(result)*, as it mentioned in the lattest jQuery specification, but it didn't work as well.

Please, help me :)

Comment: Use the JS debugger to see what your object is.

Comment: Or look at the response in the networks tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In asp.net core, by default, the serializer uses **`camelCase`** property names for json serialization. So your result will be like this

```
{"nameError":"some message","phoneError":"some message here"}
```

**Javascript is case sensitive**. So use the correct case

```
$("#nameerror").append(result.nameError);
$("#phoneerror").append(result.phoneError);
```

For reference : [MVC now serializes JSON with camel case names by default](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4842)

Comment: Thank you very much. It tooks me almost 3 hours, but I didn't found out this little trick.

Answer (score 1):

its working perfectly when i have added this line in startup file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbCrudOperation")));

    }


function Edit(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/AjacCrud/EditPahe/" + id,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (response) {

            $("#nameEmp").val(response.ID);
            console.log(response.ID);

        },
        error: function (GetError) {

            alert(GetError.responseText);

        }
    });

};
```